# How to update a dropdown value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This i my View code:

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>add_customer" method="post">

<select class="form-control" id="customer_id" name="customer_id">
    <?php foreach ( $customer as $cust ){?>
      <option value="<?php echo $datas[0]->customer_id; ?>"<?php if($cust->customer_id==$datas[0]->customer_id) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>> <?php echo $cust->customer_id; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
</form>
```

For Eg: Dropdown Value contains 1,2,3,4 actually selected value is 2 display in that field correctly. Now, I want to update the dropdown value to 4

How can I do this?  Please help..

Comment: change you `$datas[0]->customer_id` value to 4

Comment: Once I click and change the dropdown value to 4 it dispaly in the textfield but  when I click update it simply display the previous value i.e 2

Comment: change value in option to `value="<?=$cust->customer_id;?>"` see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Change values from `value="<?php echo $datas[0]->customer_id; ?>"` to this `value="<?=$cust->customer_id;?>"`*

```
<select class="form-control" id="customer_id" name="customer_id">
    <?php foreach ( $customer as $cust ){?>
      <option value="<?=$cust->customer_id;?>" <?php if($cust->customer_id == $datas[0]->customer_id) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> > <?php echo $cust->customer_id; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding

Comment: Any reason why use this value="<?=$cust->customer_id;?> instead of this line value="<?php echo $datas[0]->customer_id; ?>"

Comment: u r looping with `$customer` so options value should be of customers pretty obvious

Comment: KK bro.Now how can I get this value in jquery whether I use JSON or anyother method is there??

Comment: use `onchange event` of select to get the value of selected value, u can also make  ajax call to get the data from table